# Controler PATH into jquery AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

In my view, I have a form and an AJAX event on the form submit:

```
        var data = {
            msg1: $("#msg1").val(),
            msg2: $("#msg1").val(),
            msg3: $("#msg1").val(),
        };

        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('new_chat_msg') }}",
            data: data,
            complete: function (xhr, result) {
                console.log("ok");
            }
        });
```

I want to call my controller who's name `new_chat_msg`:

```
/**
 * Commande controller.
 *
 * @Route("/commande")
 */
class CommandeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Flush new chat message.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="new_chat_msg", options={"expose"=true})
     */
    public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
    {
        $text = $request->request->get('data');

        return new Response('Hello world!');
    }

}
```

As you can see, I use annotation for routing.
`new.html.twig` is the view where the form is.

But when I submit the form, It don't enter in the method...

So I don't know how to call the controller and pass him the JSON data...

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you imported the [routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should read this [documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html).
2. `500 Internal Server Error` usually says that you have wrong code somewhere in you code, so I can say that you have to add Action suffix to you addMsgChat action (like addMsgChatACtion)
3. another error in you code is, controller action must return Response object, so you need to return at least `return new Response()` in you action to see that it works or not

p.s: I suggest to use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) bundle for calling routes in JS files.

Comment: Thanks xurshid29, I change the controller name to ajaxAction, and I return a test response. But the problem still the same...

Comment: @Macbernie use FOSJsRoutingBundle bundle

Comment: Ok, I did, but the path generate by the bundle (Routing.generate('new_chat_msg')) is the same than before with twig ("{{ path('new_chat_msg') }}")...

Comment: @Macbernie ok, can you show your whole contoller class?

Comment: @Macbernie hmm, I don't see any invalid code in youe controller class, so there is nothing more I can say.. But, I'd do such things if I were you:): 1. check if I'am properly importing classes. 2. remove `$text = $request->request->get('data');` from the action to verify the error is coming from it or not..